# Pagination with relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having problems returning the data for two relationships when using paginate.

```
$things = $this->model->with('fruits')->with('animals')->paginate(5, ['id, 'name']);
```

Returns the "things" I want but the "fruits" and "animals" arrays are empty.

To clarify, the relationships check out, things "has Many" fruits and also "has many through (fruits)" animals.

```
public function fruits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fruit');
}

public function animals()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Animal', '\App\Fruit');
}
```

**I would like to be able to load "things" along with any relationships while being able to paginate the "things"**

Comment: It should work. Maybe you missed something.

Comment: Are you returning that data in your controller as a json response?  Or what are you doing with `$things` further down the road?  Using `with()` basically pre-fetches the related models to avoid the n+1 queries, but it does not automatically return that infromation when you return it in the controller.  You could do that using an Eloquent Resource however...

Comment: Yes. returning it's JSON into a Vuetify datatable. So I'm just returning a reference to the animals and fruits models rather than the data itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with()` only tells Eloquent to pre-fetch the related models, so you can avoid the N+1 query problem.  It does not mean that when you return the model, that information is also returned.

I would create an Eloquent Resource:

```
Class FruitResource extends \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource {
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
}


Class AnimalResource extends \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource {
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
}

Class ThingResource extends \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource {
    public function toArray($request) {         
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'fruits' => FruitResource::collection($this->fruits),
            'animals' => AnimalResource::collection($this->animals)
        ];
    }
}
```

Once you created these resource, you can alter your controller to do the following:

```
$things = $this->model->with('fruits')->with('animals')->paginate(5, ['id, 'name']);
return ThingsResource::make($things);
```

By structuring your resources, you can easily get more control on what you return.  Make life a lot nicer...

Comment: I think this is putting me on the right track. I'm getting an error though: `ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id`, Also should it be `\Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource` or `\Illuminate\Http\Resources\JsonResource`. Artisan creates the latter.

Comment: It's probably `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource` For some reason, we often have Resource in our own codebase - might need to see if I need to change that.  regarding the pagination - try and just do ->paginate(5) instead.

Comment: Turns out that "id" in the example I provided is not the primary key of the table whcih was why the above error occured. Found that you need this to include the relationships with "with". I would have thought this would be done without this having to explicitly being provided. I.e. that Laravel would determine the primary and foreign keys through the relationships. You answer was perfect for allowing me to include the related data. Thank you.

Comment: Alright - yeah, Laravel is really good, but sometimes lacks the obvious imo.  Still like working in it because it provides a good scaffolding to easily start and rapidly develop.  I would never use it without writing proper testing though; ran into similar unexpected issues myself too.  Good that my answer helped you out!